# I need to track form element on each page of angularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to track html form element on each page load on angularJS application.

```
$provide.decorator(formDirective, function ($delegate, Pdl) {
  var ngForm = $delegate[0];
  ngForm.compile = function () {
    return function (scope, element, attr) {

      Pdl.trackFormStart(attr, scope);
      attr.$observe('ngForm', function (value) {
        attr.$set('form', value);
      });
    };
  };
  return $delegate;
```

But that's not working.

it changes form action from post to get and reloads form.

How we can just track "form" html element with out affecting it's default behavior?

+++++adding few more tried outs+++++++++

As i don't want to change actual behavior of form so i tried to make copy or extend

```
angular.copy($delegate[0], ngForm);
  angular.extend($delegate[0], ngForm);
```

but its not making any copy or extend ngForm is blank

Comment: What's not working? Errors?

Comment: form submit action changed to "GET" , as once we submit, URL takes query string and reloaded.